# Do I need multiple view controllers for the iPhone & iPad storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I'm still relatively unfamiliar with all the new features of iOS 5, and what I can do in Xcode now. So, a good explanation would be appreciated.

I'm designed a single-view application and I have both an iPhone and iPad storyboard. I chose 'Single View Application' when I first started, so Xcode created a ViewController for me. Both storyboards list this view controller as their own.

Back in iOS 4 the way that I linked button actions to my view controller was to Right-Click on the button on the nib, pick the action that I wanted, then drag it over into the view controller's '.h' file, which auto-created a method/property for me.

I am confused about how to accomplish this now, since I have multiple storyboards but only one view controller. Do I need to have multiple links for each button; one for the button on the iPhone and one for the iPad? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the same way you did it in iOS4. But obviously you never built an universal app there ;-)

It's totally okay to have a single UIViewController class for two different nib files. 
And if you use storyboards it's fine to use different storyboards and a single viewController too.

You can even use the same viewController for different scenes inside a single storyboard.

The connections to the viewController are saved in the nib or storyboard. So you can't overwrite them while designing the other user interface.

Open the iPhone storyboard, make your connections to actions and outlets. Then open the iPad storyboard and make totally independent connections.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the first reply, I was under the impression that a view controller could only support two scenes in a storyboard layout. I say that because I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969730/ios-5-storyboards-classes-for-each-scene).