# iOS 5 Storyboards: Classes For Each Scene

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard

I'm new to developing with xCode and Objective C, and I have a simple question. What is the point of having seperate class files for each scene in a storyboard.

**My Question**: Why not use the default *ViewController.m* and *ViewController.h* class for every scene in your storyboard. Are there any disadvantages of using the same class for multiple scenes other than just being plain organized?

Here is a picture of where you would enter what class a specific scene is using...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtGQk.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewController is a class that manages a hierarchy of views (aka..1 screen of the application)

when you have multiple screens that do different things its a lot better to use separate view controllers (simpler too)

besides ..if you use the same class for 2 or more completely different screens Apple wont accept your app to be submitted to the App Store because it doesn't follow M-C-V model (happen to me) so its better to separate your code now..when you write it rather than separate it after you get rejected...and have to rewrite most of the app

plus..its the logistic thing..having methods from different classes in the same file its confusing as hell

also...you can't implement -viewDidLoad multiple times for different screens

and so on..i could go for some time listing reasons :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having trouble adding multiple classes. See in the image I have showed you, the drop down menu asking me to select my class doesn't show my class instead it only contains ViewController and some UI elements.

Comment: just write the name of your class directly..it will work..but be sure is subclass of UIView

Comment: @skytz: I think you mean `UIViewController` not `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

Is that even possible? Every class is going to do something different. Lets say you want to do something on DidViewLoad. How are you going to handle that for different classes? Sure you can use tag or some ivar to differentiate but it gets ugly VERY quickly. Must better to keep everything structured in their own classes. You will see what I mean once you start developing complex applications.